Ошибка "No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header" при выполнении POST-запроса (Google Firebase)
При попытке выполнить POST-запрос возникает ошибка:

Access to XMLHttpRequest at
'https://identitytoolkit.googleapis.com/v1/accounts:signIpWithPassword?key=stackoverflow'
from origin 'http://localhost:5173' has been blocked by CORS policy:
Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No
'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
resource.

auth.js:
import { ref } from 'vue'
import { defineStore } from 'pinia'

import axios from 'axios'

const apiKey = 'stackoverflow' // some api key

export const useAuthStore = defineStore('auth', () => {
  const userInfo = ref({
    token: '',
    email: '',
    userId: '',
    refreshToken: '',
    expiresIn: '',
  })

  const auth = async (payload) => {
    try {
      let response = await axios.post(
        `https://identitytoolkit.googleapis.com/v1/accounts:signIpWithPassword?key=${apiKey}`,
        {
          ...payload,
          returnSecureToken: true,
        },
      )

      userInfo.value = {
        token: response.data.idToken,
        email: response.data.email,
        userId: response.data.localId,
        refreshToken: response.data.refreshToken,
        expiresIn: response.data.expiresIn,
      }
    } catch (err) {
      switch (err.response.data.error.message) {
        case 'EMAIL_NOT_FOUND':
          error.value = 'Неверный логин или пароль'
          break
        case 'INVALID_PASSWORD':
          error.value = 'Неверный логин или пароль'
          break
        default:
          error.value =
            'Возникла ошибка. Обратитесь к администратору'
          break
      }
    }
  }
  return { auth, userInfo }
})

main.js:
import './assets/main.css'
import 'ant-design-vue/dist/reset.css'

import { createApp } from 'vue'
import { createPinia } from 'pinia'
import { initializeApp } from 'firebase/app'

import Antd from 'ant-design-vue'

import App from './App.vue'
import router from './router'

const app = createApp(App)

const firebaseConfig = {} // some config

initializeApp(firebaseConfig)

app.use(createPinia())
app.use(router)

app.use(Antd)

app.mount('#app')

В конфиге firebase localhost в качестве URL-адреса указан. Сам auth.js используется на странице авторизации:
AuthView.vue:
<script setup>
import FloatingInput from '@/components/FloatingInput.vue'

import { useAuthStore } from '@/stores/auth'
import { ref } from 'vue'

const authStore = useAuthStore()

const login = ref('')
const password = ref('')

const signin = async () => {
  await authStore.auth({ email: login.value, password: password.value })
}
</script>

<template>
  <div class="auth-page">
    <div class="auth-wrapper">
      <div class="auth-form">
        <div class="auth-form-header">
          <div class="auth-form-title">Авторизация</div>
          <div class="auth-form-description">Вход в аккаунт</div>
        </div>
        <FloatingInput v-model="login" label="Логин" type="text" />
        <FloatingInput v-model="password" label="Пароль" type="password" />
        <button type="submit" class="auth-form-button" @click="signin">
          Войти
        </button>
      </div>
      <a href="#" class="auth-advantages">Возникли вопросы?</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</template> 

Испробовал много способов, указывал хедеры в headers: {} в axios запросе — ничего не помогает 

скорее всего запрос блокируется политикой CORS
и еще у вас небольшая ошибка в https://identitytoolkit.googleapis.com/v1/accounts:signIpWithPassword?key=${apiKey}, signIpWithPassword вместо signInWithPassword

@Owlly да, действительно ошибка была в Ip вместо In... Спасибо
